# How can i get the path points of the uploaded svg file?

Tags: typescript, snap.svg

I trying to use snapsvg to extract the path and the points of the path from a svg file.

```
Snap.load("../svg/music.svg", function(loadedFragment : Snap.Fragment){
let svg = loadedFragment.select('svg');
let paths = svg.selectAll('path');

paths.forEach(function(element : Snap.Element, idx : number){
    console.log(element)
}) });
```

I can't find anything usefull in snapsvg API doc.

Comment: have you tried console.log( element.attr('d') ) ? Might also be useful if you explain what you want to do with it then, as it may help decide which exact info and format you would need.

Comment: yes, I'm working on drawing app so i need to take the points from the svg path and edit them, maybe in this format ... var points = path.points  
console.log(points[0].x + "," + points[0].y) 
and sorry about my poor english